# read strings from csv file for usage as figure meta data

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, csv

I got the following problem, I use pgfplots(table) to generate plots and tables in my latex document from generated data. I would like to read additional information from a metadata file. The reason for that, is that the data depends on the architecture it was generated on, which I would like to write into the caption. Therefore I would like to store a caption, as well as other metainfo (like axis labels) in a csv file for each plot/table and read it when generating my document.
I found datatool, xstring and some other packages which might be useful but could not figure out a way to achieve what I try to do.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you want to store the meta info in the same file as your data, or in a separate file? Are you completely flexible about the formatting of the data?

Comment: @Jake I'm completely flexible about formatting the data since I'm writing the script generating the data myself. Of course I'm flexible using one or multiple files but I would prefer one for the data and one for the meta data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read lines from a text file by first creating a `read` object using `\newread`, opening the file using `\openin` and then reading the individual lines into macros using `\read`. Then you can reuse the contents of the file in the plots or the caption:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{meta1.txt}
The first of a series of plots.
X1
Y1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{meta2.txt}
The second of a series of plots.
X2
Y2
\end{filecontents*}
\newread\myread   
\newcommand{\readmetadata}[1]{
    \openin\myread=#1
    \read\myread to \plotcaption
    \read\myread to \plotxlabel
    \read\myread to \plotylabel
    \closein\myread
}


\begin{document}

\readmetadata{meta1.txt}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=\plotxlabel,
    ylabel=\plotylabel
]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\protect\plotcaption}
\end{figure}

\readmetadata{meta2.txt}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=\plotxlabel,
    ylabel=\plotylabel
]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\protect\plotcaption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow that's a very nice solution! Thanks that completes my automated tool-chain for updating my results in my document. Very helpful! Thanks again!

Comment: found out that your solution requires one latex read per included file (had no reason until now to think about it, but yesterday I had no room for a new read). I had a short look and by moving `\newread\myread` before the command it requires only one read. Please don't consider this to be criticism, I only wanted to share my experience. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Please, put the `\newread` outside the definition of `\readmetadata`: the input stream can be reused, provided you close it after usage. So also a `\closein` instruction should appear in the definition.

Comment: @egreg: Like so?

Comment: @Jake Yes, that's the idea.